# How to set different horizontal (category) labels for each different product in MS Excel line chart

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am plotting a line graph for 3 different products in MS Excel. The x axis is revenue and the y axis is cummulative p/l. The problem is that when I set the horizontal (category labels) for each of the products (series), it also sets the same range for the two remaining products. The range for the horizontal axis for the last product that i set, modifies the horizontal ranges for the rest. The output (chart) that i get shows all lines reaching a maximum of that x value for the last set product.
Please advice me.
Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line chart has a categorical X axis. It can also use dates, but I'm not even sure if Excel 2007, which you are using, has that feature or if that came later.
In a category axis, the values of the cells don't matter. They are all in the same position.

If you want to plot the X axis points based on their value, you need to create an XY Scatter chart instead of a line chart.

[image]

Comment: thanks Teylyn, it worked. I changed it to scatter (scatter with smooth lines).